# Tkinter Label widget is not updated

Tags: python, user-interface, hash, tkinter

I tried to create a real time update on Label widget whenever the Entry widget is updated, i don't know why it seems that the data is not being process and just display what I type in Entry widget

my expectation is that the Label widget will show the result of hashing process

Here is my code

```
import hashlib
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
org_str = StringVar()
org_str.set('')

t = Entry(root, textvariable = org_str)
t.pack()

temp = str(org_str)
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(temp.encode('utf-8'))
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
org_str.set(hex_dig)

l = Label(root, textvariable = org_str, width=100)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the time you do your hash `org_str` is the empty string because the user hasn't had a chance to type anything yet.

Comment: Yes it seems only the initial data that successfully shown as hash result..
so the problem is why when the code already run, system is not pass it to the hashing process ? and instantly display what I type

Thank you for you analysis